# When flagging a comment on a heavily downvoted answer, the flag box is translucent

Tags: bug

When you flag a comment, the box looks fine:

[image: opaque]

**However**, when you flag a comment on an answer with negative votes (which itself becomes slightly translucent) the flag box is translucent and difficult to see (try it on the bottom answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203820/how-do-i-truly-reset-every-setting-in-visual-studio-2012))

[image: translucent]

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Whilst you're right, that's for answers (which is still broken), yet the bug is set to completed.

Comment: Y U no on M.SE?

Comment: @Will Good point, can it be moved to Meta StackExchange or should I just re-raise it there?

Comment: Yeah, that should not have been closed as dupe. Especially irritating since it is _my_ question..

Comment: @JonasCz The dupe brigade are out in force again unfortunately, we may have to live with translucent dialogs forever. Oh the humanity.

Comment: I'd say bring it up on mse and say specifically the bug is back.

Comment: @Will, I assume it was already mentioned on mse, and the bug is not just back, it was _never actually fixed_.

Comment: @Will On Meta SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251757/flag-dialogs-for-grayed-out-posts-are-also-grayed-out (this one was never marked status-complete)